# How to set the HTTP status code on a filter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http

How can I set the HTTP status code when a controller filter condition is not met?

For example, in the following controller

```
class FooController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :foo_filter

  def action
     respond_to :html
  end

  private

  def foo_filter
    return false unless some_conditions
  end
end
```

I would like to set the HTTP status code to 410 when calling action with `some_conditions` being false. How can I do that?

I have two applications running, one in rails 3 and another in rails 2, so I'm interested in an answer for each rails version, if different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class FooController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :foo_filter

  def action
    respond_to :html
  end

  private

  def foo_filter
    head :gone unless some_conditions
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this breaks the `DRY` principle, since I have to add the `if @gone` test for every action that is using this filter.

Comment: @fotanus Could you explain above comment?

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel he edited his answer to remove the problem. It is nice now, IMHO